# Print on screen during shutdown hook - error during saving in theme-editor.php

Tags: hooks

I'm trying to use this sample php code added to my funcion.php file:

```
function echo_shutdown(){
  echo 'test';
}
add_action( 'shutdown', 'echo_shutdown', 10 );
```

It works, i can see "test" at the bottom of my page.

The problem is that if i save my file wordpress warn me with the message: "Something went wrong. Your change may not have been saved. Please try again. There is also a chance that you may need to manually fix and upload the file over FTP."

I tried also various alternatives to echo: var_dump, print_r, exit('test'), ecc... also to use "register_shutdown_function" in place of shutdown wordpress hook. Same result.

When i try to output something during shutdown i receive this error message during saving.

There is a way to output something during shutdown hook without receive the warning?

Comment: You’ve passed the callback to the action hook incorrectly. You need to pass a string with the function name but you’re calling the function.

Comment: Thanks Jacob for your attention, i was wrong in my test function (i edited now), the problem obviously is the same

Comment: Your function works for me. Did you upload with FTP?

Comment: Can i please ask you if you tried to save 2 times? I tried on 3 different installations(different servers) and same error, but it shows up from the second time onwards i save